# Defining an equivalence relation via $x^{-1}y\in H$ w.r.t a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic, equivalence-relations

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Does the formula 
$$x^{-1}y\in H$$
define an equivalence relation *on* $G$? 
It is clear that $x^{-1}y\in H$ is both transitive and symmetric. But is it reflexive on $G$? That is to say, does the formula
$$(\forall x)(x^{-1}x\in H\Rightarrow x\in G)$$
hold? If not, then does that mean that one instead has to use the formula
$$x^{-1}y\in H\ \land\ x\in G\ \land\ y\in G$$
in order to get the desired equivalence relation on $G$?

**Edit 1:**

Obviously $x^{-1}x=e\in H$ for all $x\in G$. I want to know whether $x^{-1}x\in H$ implies $x\in G$ *without assuming that* $x\in G$.

**Edit 2:**

The question is which of the following formulas defines the desired equivalence relation on $G$:

1. $x^{-1}y\in H$
2. $x^{-1}y\in H\ \land\ x\in G\ \land\ y\in G$

Do you wish to say that these are logically the same? The usual way of checking reflexivity implicitly intersects the graph defined by (1) with $G\times G$.

**Edit 3:**

Ok it seems clear that I am not able to get my point across. Forget the part about the equivalence relation. Can one prove the formula 
$$(\forall x)(x^{-1}x\in H\Rightarrow x\in G)$$
given the assumption that $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?--Is it the case that one cannot suppose $x^{-1}x\in H$ without making any other assumptions about x? i.e. is it an ungrammatical string of symbols in set theory?

Comment: Isn't reflexive just because $e \in H$?

Comment: Yes, $x^{-1}x=e\in H$ for $x\in G$. I would like to know whether the converse holds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [equivalence classes of ∼ are left cosets of H in G - my attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805975/equivalence-classes-of-%e2%88%bc-are-left-cosets-of-h-in-g-my-attempt)

Comment: No it doesn't. Please see my edit.

Comment: I don't know whether a writing like "$x^{-1}x \in H$" without any prior statement about $x$'s membership does make sense.

Comment: Since you are attempting to prove you have an equivalence relation on $G$, you are only dealing with (ordered pairs of) elements of $G$.  Your extra condition is unnecessary.

Comment: check the definition of subgroup of a group, it must contain the identity of the group..

Comment: A binary relation is defined on a set (or a pair of sets). Implicitly, the binary relation you are interested in (and want to know whether it is an equivalence relation) is defined on $G$.  So $x$ is in $G$ to being with.

Answer (score 4):

The proof that the relation is reflexive is short and sweet.   Since $H\le G$ is a subgroup,  $e\in H$.  Thus for any $x\in G$, we have $xx^{-1}=e\in H$.  Thus $x\sim x$.

Answer (score 0):

For the reflexive property you have to show that for every $g\in G$ we have $g^{-1}g\in H$

Since $H$ is a subgroup we have $g^{-1}g=e\in H$ for every $g\in G$

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed an equivalence relation. The conditions are essy to check using the fact that groups (subgroups here) are closed under inverses and contain the identity element.